# Split camera in android

Tags: android, camera

I am working on camera application in android. I want capture two images in a single layout.Is that possible using fragments?.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `I want capture two images in a single layout.` Does it mean that user can capture 2 images and then you can display then simultaneously in fragment or what?

Comment: Pallavi thank u for replying. Can i split(divide) camera in to  two parts, as we divide layouts, each part captures image one after another.

Comment: you can simply capture 2 images and then display them along side each other...